# Media Player Error (-19,0) on CountdownTimer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, countdowntimer

I've created a program which is repeatedly call the media player every onTick method on CountdownTimer

Media Player Class

```
public class Buzzer extends Activity{
private MediaPlayer mp;
private AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
private Context context;

public Buzzer(Context context){
    super();
    this.context=context;   

}
public void playBeep(){
    play("beep.mp3");
} 


public void stop(){
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
}

private void play(String file){

    try {
         mp = new MediaPlayer();
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp.reset();
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        descriptor= context.getAssets().openFd("audios/"+file);
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}

public void onDestroy(){
     mp.stop();
     mp.release();
     super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

//Main Activity

```
      public class Main extends Activity {
      Timer timer;
      Buzzer buzzer;


      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);


               buzzer=new Buzzer(Main.this);
               timer=new Timer(24000,1000);
               timer.start();

          }

  public class Timer extends CountDownTimer{

        public ShotClock_CountdownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
          super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {

        buzzer.playBeep();  
        }
        public void onFinish() {
        }   

      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should release the media player before calling playBeep everytime.You need to release() the media players otherwise the resources are not released , and you soon get out of memory .

Comment: He has already done it if you could check out his stop() method and some other place.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Buzzer extends Activity{
private MediaPlayer mp;
private AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
private Context context;

public Buzzer(Context context){
    super();
    this.context=context;   
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.beep);
}
public void playBeep(){
    if(mp!=null ){
         mp.pause();
         mp.seekTo(0);
         mp.start();
    }
} 


public void stop(){
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause()
    }
}


public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    playBeep();
}

public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
     stop();
 }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing ? you are pause the media player in `playBeep()` & `stop()`. then what will they do ?

Comment: one instance of the mediaplayer is sufficient ...no need of creating it every time ...becaz u are having only one instance of buzzer

Comment: did u try this code .??

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp.reset();
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
 }
```

to:

```
if(mp != null){
    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.stop();
    }
    mp.release();
}else{
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

This error is happening because your MediaPlayer is in a bad state. Based on your current code, you are creating a new MediaPlayer right before you check if it is playing. Also you are only releasing `mp` if it is playing. You need to release it every time.